# Why can't I do IP route in my 3 routers triangle network?

Tags: networking, cisco

Ok so I am doing my practice in Cisco Packet Tracer and then I started to build a triangle 3 routers network.
I have already done all the IP settings and all that's left was IP routing.
I can't seem to do Ip routing between all networks, every time I tried to do Ip routing, it just didn't show on : do show IP route list.

I have already tried all IP routing but my each of my routers just showed 1 particular static IP.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is worded quite poorly so I can only guess as to what your problem is. In addition, you've not given us any of the IP networks you have configured nor the commands you used to create the static routes.

To me, it sounds like you're saying that you're adding static routes but they aren't showing up in the routing table. There are three immediate causes that come to mind but since we have so little information to go on it's not really possible to know for sure.

1. **IP routing is disabled.** This can be the default state on many switches but you've said you're configuring routers (but you haven't given us the model) so this is probably isn't the cause but it's still good to check.
2. **The address you used for your next-hop is not configured on the router.** Let's say you have a route like `ip route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1` then you MUST have `192.168.1.1` configured as an IP address on some interface.
3. **Your next-hop interface is down.** When an interface is down, any IP addresses configured on it will not participate in static routing and any routes that depend on that address will not show up in your routing table. A *dialer* interface is an exception to this rule so assuming you're not using a dialer, then check to make sure your interfaces are up.